# Launching a local host environment with vuepress gives a res.getHeader Typeerror

Tags: vuepress

Im installing vuepress using the documentation I find here:

This all works fine. However when I run:

```
vuepress dev
```

And go to my localhost:8080 I receive the following error:

```
VuePress dev server listening at http://localhost:8080/
(node:44843) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: res.getHeader is not a function
    at processRequest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vuepress/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/middleware.js:82:18)
    at ready (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vuepress/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/util.js:51:12)
    at handleRequest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vuepress/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/util.js:167:5)
    at Promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vuepress/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/middleware.js:44:7)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at middleware (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vuepress/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/middleware.js:43:12)
    at Promise.all.Promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vuepress/node_modules/koa-webpack/index.js:43:7)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vuepress/node_modules/koa-webpack/index.js:42:5
    at dispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vuepress/node_modules/koa/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:42:32)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vuepress/node_modules/@shellscape/koa-static/legacy/index.js:58:19
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vuepress/node_modules/@shellscape/koa-static/legacy/index.js:6:221)
    at _throw (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vuepress/node_modules/@shellscape/koa-static/legacy/index.js:6:455)
(node:44843) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:44843) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I tried installing:

```
npm install webpack-dev-middleware@3.6.0
```

But did does not solve my problem. Any ideas on what I can do next?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing vuepress and install it again (globally).

`sudo npm remove vuepress -g` or `npm remove vuepress`

Then:

`sudo npm install vuepress -g`